# How to include reference to library in java gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

I am coming from a C# background. I am used to NuGet and Visual Studio project references so the Java ecosystem has confused me quite a bit.

I have a gradle library project. I want to `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;`

However I keep getting cannot resolve errors.
I am using VSCode as my IDE and I would like to include the codec dependancy. How would I achieve this in VSCode/gradle.

I have downloaded the commons-codec-1.14.jar file, but don't know where to put it in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle is a tool that, among other things, manages your dependencies. This means that, you do not need to manually download and add dependencies to your project. Gradle solves this for you.

See the [official documenation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html) on how to handle dependencies with Gradle.

You probably have a *build.gradle* file, in which you need to include your dependency. It would look something like:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.14'
}
```

This lets Gradle know that you have a dependency to version *1.14* of *commons-codec* which your codes need to build and run.

This will automatically be downloaded from a remote repository, which you also can specify in your *build.gradle* file:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
```

This tells gradle to download the dependencies from Maven Central, which probably is the most typical Maven/Gradle repository and most likely hosts most dependencies you would need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
This is my dependancies object:
dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
How would I add multiple implementations, or should I be using the api field?

Comment: @UncountedBrute I don't fully understand your question here. Dependencies is a broad subject. I think any further questions you might have should be posted as separate questions. For this one, though, if you need the dependency you stated in your original question, my answer should help you.